# WrappedArray of vectors to array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, vector

I have a wrapped array of vectors as follows:

```
WrappedArray([0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [-1.0], [-1.0], [-1.0], [-1.0], [0.0], [-1.0], [0.0])
```

How can I go about converting them into a plain array?

Comment: Is this `WrappedArray` a column in a dataframe? RDD? Or do you simply have a single array?

Comment: a single array only

Comment: Which language do you use, python or scala? And can you add the code you used to create the array?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to do that by firstly converting my WrappedArray to mutable WrappedArray(this is beacuse spark returns an immutable wrapped array) and then convert it into list and then parse each element from list using a loop and do whatever conversion is required.